# What is the easiest way to solve the following linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the easiest way to solve the following linear system for $a,b,c,d,e$ in terms of $h$?

I want to do this quickly.

Are matrices the way to go?

$a+b+c+d+e=0, (-a+c+2d+3e)h=1, a+c+4d+9e=0, -a+c+8d+27e=0, a+c+16d+81e=0$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah: Gaussian elimination I reckon.